# Dynamic captcha image not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, windows-10, microsoft-edge, captcha

I have a url like `http://xxxx/xxxx.ashx`, it will show a captcha image dynamically each call, I used the url in `<img src="{here}">`, other browser work perfectly, only the Microsoft Edge not working, but Edge open a new page and directly access the url is worked, any ideas? thanks a lot.

P.S. In Edge developer tools network window, I click that image network data, the request header and response header is empty.

Microsoft Edge version: 42.17134.1.0 (17.17134)

Comment: For testing purpose, Try to create a new user account and than try to use the MS Edge with in it to check whether it helps to load the image or not. If issue persist than try to post a sample code which loads any sample image from your web service. It can help us to test the issue on our end.

Answer (score 0):

Check that http://xxxx/xxxx.ashx is returning a header with a mime type image.

You need to check on your serverside language-platform how to return a header in the response, specifically the mime type.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

However is strange... usually using a url in  does not require to specify the mime type header... at least on most cases.

Comment: the response mine type is image/gif @ chrome.